# Defining constraints programatically on objects defined using Interface builder

Tags: ios, macos, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to *develop a Mac OS X application*, which requires me to change the constraints on the views present in main window depending on the user's choice, probably *a drop down menu will be provided to user to change layout of the views contained in*.

Application contains several custom views, so I wish not to define all objects within the code itself, rather I wish to define objects using Interface Builder and apply/modify constraints as per the user's response programatically using NSLayoutConstraint API. 
**Is it possible to use NSLayoutConstraint API to define constraints programatically on the objects defined using Interface Builder ? If yes then how ?**

Comment: Of course. You can connect UI elements *and* constraints via `@IBOutlet` and then manipulate them in code. Pretty basic.

Comment: So can I apply constraints on UI elements, programatically without using NSLayoutConstraint API ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by *"without using NSLayoutConstraint API"*

Comment: I want the constraints on UI elements to change dynamically i.e., I'll define a certain set of constraints & user can choose one among the set of constraints. Can this be accomplished using @IBOutlet ? Sorry If the question's answer is too obvious, I am new to Mac OS X development.

Answer (score 0):

Simple examples (using Swift):

```
// connect a button to an outlet
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: NSButton!

// then, in your code, set the Width constraint to 300
myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
```

---

```
// connect an Interface Builder defined constraint to an outlet
@IBOutlet weak var theTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// then, in your code, change it to 12
theTopConstraint.constant = 12
```

---

You can also `.addContraints()` `.removeConstraints()` `.updateConstraints()` etc, etc, etc.